# Panel data stargazer - Not including factor variables

Tags: r, rstudio, panel-data, stargazer

I wanted to ask when doing panel data models: random, fixed and LSDV using `lm` function. When using stargazer to get nice table of results, we get a additional variables coef for all cross section dummy coefs. like in the example below:

```
#Load packages
library(foreign)
library(plm)
library(stargazer)

#Load in Wooldridge data on crime
crime <- read.dta("http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/crime4.dta")

#Declare our data to be a panel data set
crime.p <- pdata.frame(crime,index=c("county","year"))

#Run a panel model
#fixed effects / within
fixedeff <- plm(log(crmrte) ~ polpc + lwtuc + avgsen + wfed + d82 + d82 + d84 + d85,data=crime.p,model="within")

#Random effects
randomeff <- plm(log(crmrte) ~ polpc + lwtuc + avgsen + wfed + d82 + d82 + d84 + d85,data=crime.p,model="random")

#LSDV
LSDV <- lm(log(crmrte) ~ polpc + lwtuc + avgsen + wfed + d82 + d82 + d84 + d85 + factor(county)-1, data=crime.p)

stargazer(fixedeff, randomeff, LSDV, type = "text")
```

Is there a way how to have a nice table and do not have all `factor(county)` coefs in it?

I know we can do it "by hand" when printing the table, however I need this inside a function So I NEED `type = "text"`.

Comment: Looking at `?stargazer`, there are quite a few options for `omit = ...`. Maybe that helps?

Comment: I know about `omit` argument, I dont know how to implement it in script

Comment: I think if you boiled it down to your exact problem with a minimum reproducable example (including data, e.g. use `mtcars` or similar), it would be easier for people to help you. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Right now we have to guess what the problem with `omit` might be.

Comment: Hi @Petr if the solutions works for you, I'd love to get an upvote. Best regards, Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as coeffeinjunky said, it should work with `omit`. Add it as option to `stargazer`:

```
stargazer(fixedeff, randomeff, LSDV, type = "text", omit=c("county"))
```

Is this the output you're looking for?